# eigenspaces as lines

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am reading the proof that number of free parameters in rank-$r$ $n$ by $n$ Hermitian matrix is $2nr -r^2$ (first answer in [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110189/number-of-parameters-needed-to-specify-a-hermitian-matrix-of-rank-r)), which says "Their eigenspaces are orthogonal lines. One line depends on n−1 complex parameters, the next line must be perpendicular to the first, so it depends on n−2 complex parameters, and so on...."

What is this 'line' exactly referring to? and why does one line depends on (n-1) complex parameters, and so on until (n-r)? I think I got the intuitive picture of the proof, but it'd be great if I could understand the idea of 'line' (related to the idea of eigenvectors) and how it's used here in more details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an initial note: It might help visually to think of the real ($\mathbb R$) case, (and maybe replace the word "Hermitian" with "symmetric").

Note that if you have an eigenvector $v$ of a matrix, any scalar multiple of $v$ is also an eigenvector of the same eigenvalue:
$$A(kv) = kAv = k\lambda v = \lambda(kv)$$
so it makes more sense to think of the whole subspace $$\langle v \rangle = \{kv~,~ k\in \mathbb C\}$$ at once.

Again, if you picture $\mathbb R$, this is a (real) 1-dimensional subspace, a "line". When dealing with $\mathbb C$, some still call a (complex) 1-dimensional subspace a "line" (maybe even a "complex line"), even though it is (real) 2-dimensional. The reason for doing so is a lot of the quick intuition works out.

For example, "a line in $n$ dimensions depends on $n-1$ parameters". This statement describes both the real and complex cases. So just picture the real case.

How does a line depend on $n-1$ parameters? How do we describe the line $\langle v \rangle$ mentioned above?
Well I can define a vector $v$ by specifying its $n$ components.
Then as long as $v\neq 0$, this defines the line $\langle v \rangle$.
$$v = \begin{pmatrix}v_1 \\ v_2 \\ \vdots \\ v_n \end{pmatrix}$$
This would initially seem like there are $n$ free parameters, but scaling the vector by $k$ doesn't change the line, so there are really only $n-1$ free parameters (i.e. dimensions).